# Building a DIY window-opener

Tags: windows, tools

In my bathroom is one small window, which handle is 3 m above ground. Underneath the window stands my washing machine, so after showering, to get the humidity out, I need to climb on the washing machine in order to open the window. That is somewhat annoying and I am afraid the top of the machine will break through someday.

So I did some research for products to open windows which are hard to reach because of the place they are build or for disabled people living in places which weren't constructed for somebody with a wheelchair, for example. I found these to website offering what I was looking for (sorry that both are in German, but I guess the pictures ([1](https://www.ft-creations.de/produkte/fenstergriffverlaengerung/), [2](https://fenstergriff-verlaengerung.de/epages/fe26cc2c-cde1-4f2f-a3dd-71a27d8d403a.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath=/Shops/fe26cc2c-cde1-4f2f-a3dd-71a27d8d403a/Categories/%22Fenster%C3%B6ffner%20kaufen%22)) give enough information).

The window looks like this. 6 o'clock position of the handle is closed, 9 o'clock is open, I don't need the 12 o'clock position.

[image]

However with costs more than 60 €, I wondered if somebody had an idea on how to DIY build something that fits the purpose and is not expensive.

Comment: I guess you do have the type of windows pictured on those product pages?  How hard is it to operate the handle on your windows?

Comment: The windows are only 2 years old, built in when the flat was renovated. They are easy to operate with a little resistance when hitting the 9 o'clock position.

Comment: https://smile.amazon.com/Reacher-Grabber-VIVE-Rotating-Extension/dp/B00O47NWE6/ref=sr_1_3_a_it?ie=UTF8&qid=1513703611&sr=8-3&keywords=reacher+grabber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My immediate thoughts are to get a large diameter wooden dowel (30-40mm, sold as stair railings or closet rods) and screw a large eye-bolt into the top of that and use it just as the tool you pictured.

[image]

Wrap the eye with tape or something so it doesn't scratch up your handle.

Another option, depending on the diameter of your handle, would be to get the wooden dowel and drill a large perpendicular hole through the end big enough for the handle to fit in.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the excellent idea with the large eye bolt, I like it! I'll not mark the question answered yet to give others the chance to come up with something else.

Comment: Yes it is customary to wait on the check mark.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The window handle should have an eye (ring) on the end of it.   You use a stick with a hook on the end to open and close the window.

Comment: There are no eyes on the end of the handles.

Comment: @blabbath then it has the wrong handles.  Oh, I see, the flat was renovated.  Yes, when they renovated, the window peolple fit the wrong handles because they didn't give any attention to detail, or they used a stock window type that doesn't allow for handles with eyes.

Comment: It is possible that the handle can be exchanged for one that is designed to be  operated conveniently by a pole with a certain end fitting on it. It is absolutely unacceptable and possibly a violation of the rental code to have a window at that height which cannot be operated from the floor.

Comment: @JimStewart I agree totally and I would certainly hope so.  Those high windows are hardly rare in Europe.

Comment: I like the banister rod idea with the screw eye driven into the end. Keep the rod as short as possible; keeps it light weight.  An oversize eye will make the handle easy to grab. A note as to logistics and ease for the eye grabbing the handle, instead of installing the eye directly out of the end of the rod which could prove cumbersome and difficult align, you could predrill  the hole for the eye at a 45* angle out the end of the rod.  This would allow for all kings of alignment adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

Consider having an exhaust fan installed for the area.
If you also have a clothes dryer in the area and it is vented outside properly, consider a setting of no-heat tumble action for a short period of time.  Set timer for 15-Minutes. This will exhaust the area in short order at very little cost. And less painful that a fall from the top of the washer.

Comment: Exhaust fan isn't an option, the flat is for rent and the owner won't install something, since the bathroom has a window and can thus be ventilated...